# How to insert a newline with amended text in Python if conditions are met?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3.6. I have a text file test.txt and I read it line by line.
In the text file, I have multiple entries of Titles like: TitleX, TitleY, TitleZ.

I want that IF a line contains 4 consecutive 1 1 1 1 on it to enter a new line below it (after the last 1 1 1 1 entry on each region (within a Title)) and write as a text "TitleX2", "TitleY2", "TitleZ2" and so on depending on the previous title to add 2 after it. So strings should be used.

This is what I have for the moment:

```
filepath = 'test.txt'
with open(filepath) as fp:
line = fp.readline()
cnt = 1
while line:
print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt,line.strip()))
line = fp.readline()
# if(line contains 1 1 1 1 and is the last of that type) then insert new line 
#below it with string "Title2" depending on which 
#regions the 1 1 1 1 belongs to (such as TitleX,TitleY, or TitleZ) as there are hundreds of those 
#Titles in the text file.
cnt += 1
```

Text file is like this:

- TitleX
- 1234
- 51421
- 1231512
- 12521
- 1 1 1 1
- 1 1 1 1
- 1 1 1 1

#Should insert TitleX2 here

- 1151261
- TitleY
- 35126
- 124125
- 1 1 1 1
- 1 1 1 1

#Should insert TitleY2 here

- 12512512
- TitleZ

#and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is you want

```
index = 0
insert = False
currentTitle = ""
testfile = open("test.txt","r")    
content = testfile.readlines()
finalContent = content
testfile.close()
# Add as much titles in list
titles = ["TitleX","TitleY","TitleZ"]   

for line in content:
    index = index + 1
    for title in titles:
        if line in title+"\n":    
            currentTitle = line
            print (line)
    if line == "1 1 1 1\n":
        insert = True
    if (insert == True) and (line != "1 1 1 1\n"):
        finalContent.insert(index-1, currentTitle[:6] + "2" + currentTitle[6:])
        insert = False

f = open("test.txt", "w")
finalContent = "".join(finalContent)
f.write(finalContent)
f.close()
```

Comment: For filereading the best practice is using `with open(filepath) as f:` as seen in the replies below. This will lead to your system appropriately closing the file, even if things go wring between open and f.close()

Answer (score 2):

You can use \n inside the string. This should produce a new line.

I believe this should help:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-new-line-and-how-to-python-print-without-a-newline/

[https://www.pitt.edu/~naraehan/python2/tutorial7.html#:~:text=In%20Python%20strings%2C%20the%20backslash,r%22%20is%20a%20carriage%20return.&text=Conversely%2C%20prefixing%20a%20special%20character,it%20into%20an%20ordinary%20character](https://www.pitt.edu/%7Enaraehan/python2/tutorial7.html#:%7E:text=In%20Python%20strings%2C%20the%20backslash,r%22%20is%20a%20carriage%20return.&text=Conversely%2C%20prefixing%20a%20special%20character,it%20into%20an%20ordinary%20character).

I also created some indentation. Let me know if this helps!

```
if "1 1 1 1" in line:
    line.replace("1 1 1 1", "\nTitle2")
    print(line)
    #This will add a new line with Title2 in the string
```

```
filepath = 'test.txt'
with open(filepath) as fp:
   line = fp.readline()
   cnt = 1
   while line:
      print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt,line.strip()))
      line = fp.readline()
      # if(line contains 1 1 1 1) then insert new line below it with string "Title2" depending on which 
      #regions the 1 1 1 1 belongs to (such as TitleX,TitleY, or TitleZ) as there are hundreds of those 
      #Titles in the text file.
      cnt += 1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. I know about that (\n), the problem is that I need to apply the condition (please see above) - (if line contains 1 1 1 1 then check the first Title in the region which is variable and add the \n with the previous Title adding 2 after it.

Comment: @Nytro I updated my answer, you can use repalce() once you find the line that contain "1 1 1 1" and it can change it to a new line with the title you want

Answer (score 1):

This should help:

```
with open(filepath) as fp:
    contents = fp.read().split('\n')
    content_new = []
    for line in contents:
        content_new.append(line)
        if line.strip() == "1 1 1 1":
            content_new.append("Title X2")
    # now write to file again
    fp.writelines(contents_new)
```

You can also consider saving the last title in a separate variable, and check if the current line is a new title.

Comment: May I notice that a downvote is unnecessary, if the answer above copied parts of my answer by editing after I submitted my post?