# How to post a new line at the end of each Title region with Title[Name]2 if there are at least 5 consecutive lines within each region?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I guess the easiest way to achieve posting a new line with *Title[Name]2 at the end of each *Title region where there at least 5 consecutive lines containing 1 1 1 1 would be via a variable that counts the number of consecutive lines within each *Title region.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with the counting variable (perhaps, indeed it has to be reset after each *Title region)

```
transitions = dict()
in_region = False
reg_end = -1
current_title = None
cnt = 0
with open("test.txt","r") as testfile:
    content = testfile.readlines()

for idx, line in enumerate(content):
    if line.startswith('*Title '):
        # Commit last transition before this to dict, if any
        if current_title:
            transitions[reg_end] = current_title
            while "1 1 1 1" in line:
                cnt+=1
                if cnt>5:
        # add suffix for printing
                    current_title = line.rstrip('\n') + '2\n'
    elif line.endswith(' 1 1 1 1\n'):
        in_region = True
    elif in_region:
        in_region = False
        reg_end = idx-1
        if current_title:
            transitions[reg_end] = current_title

with open("test.txt", "w") as output:
    for idx, line in enumerate(content):
        output.write(line)
        if idx in transitions:
            output.write(transitions[idx])
```

Example:

```
*Title Test
sometext 1 1 1 1
anothertext 1 1 1 1
#Not expecting *Title Test2 on this line.
whatever
asdas 1 1 1 1 
rthtr 1 1 1 1 
asdasf 1 1 1 1 
asfasf 1 1 1 1 
blabla 1 1 1 1 
#Expecting *Title Test2 on this line.
124124124
*Title Alpha
sfdiasas 1 1 1 1 
qwdqwqd 1 1 1 1
#Not expecting *Title Alpha2 on this line.
someothertexting
sdsdfds 1 1 1 1 
sdasda 1 1 1 1
egrwefw 1 1 1 1 
poeifwio 1 1 1 1
dkvnsjc 1 1 1 1 
kdnwwjkev 1 1 1 1
#Expecting *Title Alpha2 on this line.
#and so on for thousands of them..
```

Thank you!

Comment: show us 2 or 3 lines from test.txt to have clear idea and debugging.

Comment: @Cyber-Tech hi, they are posted above after Example: (that's the test.txt)

Comment: This is a followup for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63312712/add-new-line-after-finding-last-string-in-a-region which in turn is a followup for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63307257/how-to-insert-a-newline-with-amended-text-in-python-if-conditions-are-met

Comment: Your example omits some corner casee which really should be covered at least in the actuad requirements. Can there be several regions in the same Title section which should have another line added? Are there Title sections which don't contain any interesting regions?

Comment: Also think about how you can reduce this to a [mre]. The overwriting of the destination file is not important for your question, so you could trim out that part. Reading the lines from the file is also not part of your question, so the code (and any solution) could simply process a list of strings in memory. This makes it easier to answer, and lets us focus on your specific question.

Comment: @tripleee re:1st question: as per se there should be 1 region per 1 *Title. Now, most *Titles (so regions) have multiple consecutive 1 1 1 1 in their lines but the insertion of a new line with *Title [Name]2 should be made just after there are at least 5 consecutive lines containing 1 1 1 1 within a region (within a *Title)

Comment: So that should be the rule, if say there are 2-3-4 consecutive lines containing 1 1 1 1 there shouldn't be an insertion of a newline with *Title [Name]2 within that specific region (*Title)

Comment: @tripleee re:2nd question well the input is test.txt from where it reads the lines, and after processing I guess it should also write it back. I copy the input file before running the code and then compare with the output overwritten file.

Comment: You are restating requirements which are already in the question, and not clarifying anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added code in the part which happens when we see a new `*Title` line, but of course the counter should be incremented when you are in a region where the current line ends with `1 1 1 1`. Here is a refactoring which moves things around a bit for your new requirement.

```py
transitions = dict()
reg_count = 0
reg_end = -1
current_title = None

with open("test.txt","r") as testfile:
    content = testfile.readlines()
    
for idx, line in enumerate(content):
    if line.startswith('*Title '):
        current_title = line.rstrip('\n') + '2\n'
    elif line.strip().endswith(' 1 1 1 1'):
        reg_count += 1
        reg_end = idx
    elif reg_count:
        if current_title and reg_count >= 5:
            transitions[reg_end] = current_title
        reg_count = 0
if current_title and reg_count >= 5:
    transitions[reg_end] = current_title

with open("test.txt", "w") as output:
    for idx, line in enumerate(content):
        output.write(line)
        if idx in transitions:
            output.write(transitions[idx])
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/pJaVvq

If you want to develop this further, add `print` statements which show the value of pertinent variables in each section so you can see what's going on when the program processes a simple file. I don't believe you can make meaningful changes to code before you understand how it works.

Comment: Thanks, perhaps I am doing something wrong, but I can't make it to overwrite over the test.txt (input file)

Comment: Can't how? The demo I linked to is certainly doing exactly that, and I didn't change anything in that part of the program, so if it was working before, it should still be working now; and anyway, as pointed out above, you are making this harder for everyone by not focusing on a [mre].

Comment: Sorry, had a syntax error. Works now, as in the Demo. Solved, thanks!