# Conditions on finding string

Tags: python

I am trying to manually input a Carmodel and when this is found within that defined region to look for another subregion named 'Date' within the first region and after it to add the line with the following string "For rent". Something like this (Please see below the expected output highlighted with #, within example.txt)

```
#Region1 starts here
Carname 
"Ford Ranger"
Color "Red"
Mileage "1024"
#Subregion1 starts here
Date
11/02/2018
/
#Subregion1 ends here
#Region1 ends here
#Add line here "For rent"
#Region2 starts here
Carname 
"Toyota Prius"
Color "Red"
Mileage "1024"
#Subregion2 starts here
Date
10/06/2019
/
#Subregion2 ends here
#Region2 ends here
#Add line here "For rent"
```

This list continues for hundreds of entries in the .txt file, every Carname respresent a new Region with its own subregion.

But it should target just 1 at a time as it should look for manual user input. For the above example the manual input would be:"Ford Ranger"

This is what I've tried but I got stuck:

```
transitions = dict()
in_region = False
reg_end = -1
current_title = None
carmodel = input("input carmodel:")

with open("example.txt","r") as testfile:
    content = testfile.readlines()

for idx, line in enumerate(content):
    if line.startswith('Carname'):
    #if line.startswith ('Date') within the input 'Carmodel'
    #if line.endswith ('/') within the Date region
        # Commit last transition before this to dict, if any
        if current_title:
            transitions[reg_end] = current_title
        # add suffix for printing
        current_title = 'For rent\n'
    elif line.strip().startswith(carmodel):
        in_region = True
        # This will be overwritten while we remain in the region
        reg_end = idx
    elif in_region:
        in_region = False

if current_title:
    transitions[reg_end] = current_title

with open("example.txt", "w") as output:
    for idx, line in enumerate(content):
        output.write(line)
        if idx in transitions:
            output.write(transitions[idx])
```

This is more of a followup of this:
[Crosspost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63314680/how-to-post-a-new-line-at-the-end-of-each-title-region-with-titlename2-if-ther)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: what is `carname` ? also what error did u get?

Comment: @AdhunThalekkara Carname is the keyword that defines the beginning of each region, I didn't get errors, I just got stuck. In the above example the input would be:"Ford Ranger" it looks for it, it finds it, then that's a region. Within that regions it looks below and find the subregion Date, and after it, it has to insert some text ("For rent")

Comment: i mean the `carname` variable

Comment: @AdhunThalekkara, Carname is a piece of string that appears probably thousands of times within the example.txt, beneath it is the Carmodel variable (Ford Ranger, Toyota Prius, etc...), this is where each region begins.

Comment: `elif line.strip().startswith(carname):` we are talking about this same line right?

Comment: @AdhunThalekkara, right, sorry! That was a typo it should be, elif line.strip().startswith(carmodel): , please see the above edit. Thanks!

Comment: are you sure you are using "" this while u gving input because the code works just fine. the for rent line added just after the "Ford Ranger" line in .txt

Comment: @AdhunThalekkara  yes I am, I have some missing commented lines in the code as I got stuck. It's not just those lines within the example, there are thousands of those lines....Please see the re-edited example as above.

Comment: @AdhunThalekkara the above lines containing #were added by me manually just as an example to the desired output.

Comment: can you come in the chat?https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219834/discussion-between-nytro-and-adhun-thalekkara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try some thing like this.

```
transitions = dict()
in_region = False
reg_end = -1
current_title = None
carmodel = input("input carmodel:")

with open("example.txt","r") as testfile:
    content = testfile.readlines()
find_date_line=False
for idx, line in enumerate(content):
    if find_date_line:
        if line.strip().startswith('/'):
            reg_end = idx
            find_date_line = False
    else:
        if line.startswith('Carname'):
        #if line.startswith ('Date') within the input 'Carmodel'
        #if line.endswith ('/') within the Date region
            # Commit last transition before this to dict, if any
            if current_title:
                transitions[reg_end] = current_title
            # add suffix for printing
            current_title = 'For rent\n'
        elif line.strip().startswith(carmodel):
            in_region = True
            # This will be overwritten while we remain in the region
            # reg_end = idx
            find_date_line=True
        elif in_region:
            in_region = False

if current_title:
    transitions[reg_end] = current_title
with open("example.txt", "w") as output:
    for idx, line in enumerate(content):
        output.write(line)
        if idx in transitions:
            output.write(transitions[idx])
```

when u provide input

```
"Ford Ranger"
```

output file will be like

```
#Region1 starts here
Carname 
"Ford Ranger"
Color "Red"
Mileage "1024"
#Subregion1 starts here
Date
11/02/2018
/
For rent
#Subregion1 ends here
#Region1 ends here
#Add line here "For rent"
#Region2 starts here
Carname
"Toyota Prius"
Color "Red"
Mileage "1024"
#Subregion2 starts here
Date
10/06/2019
/
#Subregion2 ends here
#Region2 ends here
#Add line here "For rent"
```